# Math formula for finding 'HH:MM:SS:MMM' Timecode given a number of frames and FPS?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I have been at this for a few days and while I have made progress I am stuck on the last bit, getting timecode to display as `HH:MM:SS:MS` rather than `HH:MM:SS:FF`. To do this I need a formula for the milliseconds part

I know this is will be complicated for Drop-Frame Timecodes so I have ruled them out. I am only concerned with NDF Timecodes.

The formula I have for finding a NDF Timecode, for example a video of 30 frames with a 12 FPS:

1. To get the hours, `30 / (12* 3600)`, `3600` is the number of seconds in a hour
2. To get the minutes, `30 / (12 * 60) - (0 * 60)`, `0` is the sum from step 1
3. To get the seconds, `(30 / 12) - ( (0 * 3600) - (0 * 60)`
4. To get the frames, `30 % 12` (Modulas)

The Timecode would be `00:00:02:06`, as shown at [Frames to Timecode Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/frames-to-timecode?c=GBP&v=frames:30,fpses:12).

I would like to make a slight tweak at step 4, to instead get the milliseconds needed for format `HH:MM:SS:MMM`. I have tried to unsuccessfully solve it on my own, I searched around and turned up with nothing too.

I am not a math wizard by any chance, not even a half rate one. I would really like to learn how to do this though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will notice this is a Math forum. The questions here should just be about mathematics. You cannot expect the forum users to just know about any technical things that are not part of mathematics itself. So spewing out technical jargon such as "Drop Frame Timecodes", "NDF Timecodes", "FPS", "HH:MM:SS:FF", "HH:MM:SS:MS" without explanation *severely* cuts down on the number of people who will respond.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I appreciate your wisdom. You are right. I will rewrite this post, or maybe just delete it and work on a better question, thank you.